# Changing the retention period of kafka during run time

Tags: apache-kafka, retention

HI I want to reduce the retention period of the Kafka.

so , How to reduce the retention during the run time and so as to not required to restart the Kafka service.

Note: I want to do retention at global level of Kafka and not topic level.

Answer (score 3):

As [Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) described in Broker configs section under the following sub topic

> **Updating Default Topic Configuration**
>
> Default topic configuration options used by brokers may be updated
> without broker restart. The configs are applied to topics without a
> topic config override for the equivalent per-topic config. One or more
> of these configs may be overridden at cluster-default level used by
> all brokers.

You can change dynamically Kafka topic default configs in cluster level. For retention period you can change below configs.

> - log.retention.ms
> - log.retention.minutes
> - log.retention.hours

You can see other config list in the documentation.

But again according to documentation [log.retention.hours](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_log.retention.hours) and [enter link description here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_log.retention.minutes) configurations' update mode in `read-only` and [log.retention.ms](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_log.retention.ms) is `cluster-wide`

So as stated in [**3.1.1 Updating Broker Configs**](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#dynamicbrokerconfigs)

> From Kafka version 1.1 onwards, some of the broker configs can be
> updated without restarting the broker. See the Dynamic Update Mode
> column in Broker Configs for the update mode of each broker config.
>
> - `read-only`: Requires a broker restart for update
> - `per-broker`: May be updated dynamically for each broker
> - `cluster-wide`: May be updated dynamically as a cluster-wide default. May also be updated as a per-broker value for testing.

So only you can change **`log.retention.ms`**

**config updating command for all brokers**

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --entity-type brokers --entity-default --alter --add-config log.retention.ms=3600000
```

output

```
Completed updating default config for brokers in the cluster.
```

to verify if the config upodated in the cluster level, run following describe command

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --entity-type brokers --entity-default --describe
```

output

```
Default configs for brokers in the cluster are:
  log.retention.ms=3600000 sensitive=false synonyms={DYNAMIC_DEFAULT_BROKER_CONFIG:log.retention.ms=3600000}
```

If you need to remove or reset the config again, run

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --entity-type brokers --entity-default --alter --delete-config log.retention.ms
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of the Kafka (using Kraft) (which is currently 3.3.2) you can change the retention of the specified topic using the following command.

```
/bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server <the-ip-of-the-broker>:9092 --topic <specified-topic> --alter --add-config retention.ms=<retention-ms>
```